# Reference for an extension theorem for Neumann boundary data

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, extension

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth bounded domain (we denote by $n$ the normal to $\partial\Omega$) and $p\in(1,\infty)$. Do you know where I can find (book or article) a reference for this result:

> For $(f,g)\in W^{2-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega) \times W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega)$ let $u:= T(f,g) \in W^{2,p}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\Tr(u)=f$ and $\Tr(\nabla u)\cdot n = g$. Then the operator $T : W^{2-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega) \times W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial\Omega) \to W^{2,p}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ exists and is continuous.

This somewhat differs from the usual extension theorem of Gagliardo: if one has $g \in W^{1-1/p}(\partial\Omega)$ then it can be extended to $\tilde{g}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ but it is not trivial to infer the construction of $u$ from this.

I did not find a reference for this in the literature.